# Visual Studio 2015 Peek Definition Icon not shown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, peek

I updated Extensibility Tools today.
I found Peek Definition is not working.
Anybody can help me to make it work.

Thanks
Joon

Comment: Does Ctrl + Click not working? please use ALT+ F12 and check if it works.

Comment: Ctrl + and ALT + F12 is working. But On the top of the left, above  the private or public, there was number of object which refer this method was shown before. But now gone. I want to know how  to get it back.

Comment: The number shown on the above of some method is like "3references" like that.

Comment: I found and reset it as : Tools ->Text Editor ->All Languages ->CodeLens and checked Enable CodeLens.

Comment: Since you resolve the issue, please write an answer, and mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and made it enabled as follows:

Tools -> Options ->Text Editor ->All Languages ->CodeLens and check Enable CodeLens checkbox.